# Adding recaptcha using Ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

I made a form for the class.

I applied couple of validation rules and in last just stuck on this. I added recaptcha simple English means Google Human verification for my form. I am using server side validation. I am not going for client side validation as i knew its recommended by developers but for this I am using server-side. The problem is Recaptcha not sending the post response to server and the code error is undefined index: . All the arrays visible on print_r except captcha.
Anyone know how to resolve this .?

```
captcha: <div class="g-recaptcha" id="captcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxx"></div>
php:

$select = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['select']);
$box = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, validation(($_POST["box"])));
$captcha = ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]);


On Client side Ajax: 
var select  = $("#select").val();
var box  = $("#box").val();
var captcha  = $("#captcha").val();
var submit  = $("#submit").val();
      $(".danger").load("testings.php", {
        select: select,
        box: box,
        captcha: captcha,
        submit: submit
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
var captcha  = $("#captcha").val();
```

change it to

```
var captcha  = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val()
```

Google automatically creates a hidden element with this id that stores the value of **g-recaptcha-response**

Also since you are passing the value as "captcha" you'd have to update this line as well

```
$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"] to $_POST["captcha"]
```

Comment: it means should i remove the id from <div> tags .?

what about the next one .? 
captcha: chaptcha, or captcha: g-recaptcha-response like this .?

Comment: Yeah, id="captcha" is unnecessary if you are not using it anywhere else.

Comment: I updated the answer. Either change the variable in JS, "captcha" to "g-recaptcha-response" or in PHP side change "g-recaptcha-response" to "captcha" ...I hope that made sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the problem is that the  value of recaptcha won't be set in the div with id #captcha.
Do you test sending the form in the ajax like that?
let form = $(form).serialize();

and after that, send the form through you Ajax?